# Sending header data to laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building an API for a webapp I made to train myself in Laravel. I integrated a token based authentication system by Tappleby, like this:

```
Route::get('api/v1/auth', 'Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenController@index');

Route::post('api/v1/auth', 'Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenController@store');

Route::delete('api/v1/auth', 'Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenController@destroy');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.token'], function ()
{

    Route::resource('user', 'ApiUsersController');

});
```

In `ApiUsersController` I, ideally, want to do something like this:

```
public function index() 
{

    $payload = $request->header('X-Auth-Token');

    if(empty($payload)) {

          return $this->respondNotFound('User does not exist.');

    }

    $user = $this->driver->validate($payload);

    return $user;

}
```

However, `header()` is not available for the controller. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel, you can retrieve the HTTP headers like so:

```
$value = Request::header('Content-Type');
```

Add this to your controller and you can then do what you need to with it.

Also, you can change Content-Type to whatever it should be.

Read more here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests